# Yii - sort dataprovider with more than one field

Tags: sorting, yii, dataprovider

I am using DataProvider to show some data. The data is related to shows in the theater. I want to show the shows which are "On Season" first and then the shows that are not on season. And all the shows should be ordered alphabetically. I tried to use CSort but I am getting an error. Here is my code:

```
$dataProviderFiaba = new CActiveDataProvider('Show',
                    array(
                        'criteria'=>array(
                            'condition'=>'show_type= '.Show::TYPE_FIABA,
                        ),
                        'sort'=>array(
                            'defaultOrder'=>'on_season', //TO SHOW THE ON SEASON SHOWS FIRST
                            'asc'=>'title', // TO ORDER ALPHABETICALLY
                        ),
                    ));
```

And the error is `Property "CSort.asc" is not defined.` So I think I am not using CSort with the correct format. What is the right way to do this kind of sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use "asc" in the context of attributes for CSort. For example:
`$mCSort->attributes = array('title'=>array('asc'=>'title', 'desc' => 'title DESC'));`

To solve your sorting problem, the following should be sufficent though:

```
$dataProviderFiaba = new CActiveDataProvider('Show',
                    array(
                        'criteria'=>array(
                            'condition'=>'show_type= '.Show::TYPE_FIABA,
                            'order'=>'on_season, title'
                        ),
                    ));
```